# Is it possible to use chrome sync storage in debug mode?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing my chrome extension locally (not yet published it in chrome store) and want to test `chrome.storage.sync`. I have created a following manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDK0/UzjTVn4NTS1QVIHy93R+L8SAFm2TvBwUmKtc07oBUB3Gx1HP+iheM8Laogx84a0tdnCP1YE4apcBJ4yeIuZ+WqNMlhsvD69Of1YnPWruOn1psgJ6R2xPDY1FsC3GWiot35S9jHBChTy82SHaEJ5b0defoVs+hyEfWwLK34zwIDAQAB",
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*/*" ],
      "js": [
        "jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
        "underscore-min.js",
        "inpage.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And following `inpage.js` file that adds synchronized editbox at the bottom of any webpage:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( 'body' ).append( "<input type='text' id='foo'/>" );
  $( '#foo' ).on( 'change', function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ foo: $( '#foo' ).val() });
  });
  chrome.storage.sync.get( 'foo', function( arg ) {
    $( '#foo' ).val( arg.foo );
  });
});
```

All works fine, but if i delete and re-add my extension (emulating user computer change) my data is not restored. Do i miss something in my code or sync storage works `only` with public apps published on chrome store?

Comment: By removing your extension you are not emulating computer change. You are emulating "I don't want this extension on my computer any more", so Chrome deletes any data it has in storage. Also, make sure that you have enabled syncing for your account (or else `storage.sync` will behave the same as `storage.local`).

Comment: I enabled syncing in my account. Is it a way for extension to keep it's data on delete/uninstall pattern?

Comment: Not that I know of (and it is a good thing, I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it's working as intended: removing extension will also delete all data associated with it.